# AS3 Load Image from Server using Loader

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, loader, externalinterface

Hey, Im trying to load an image from my server with flash.  The point is to do this dynamically so that I can animate it in flash on the fly.  Im using ExternalInterface so I can feed flash some variables from javascript, but that doesnt seem to be the problem.  I have ExternalInterface all sorted out it would seem.  Anyway here is the problem code.

```
function getCover(){
    var year = "slices";
    var cover = "book-face.png"
    var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressStatus);
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderReady);

    var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("howbizarro.org/clients/westessex/" + year + "/" + cover);
    myLoader.load(fileRequest);
    //Book.addChild(myLoader);
    //Book.play();

    function onProgressStatus(e:ProgressEvent) {   
      // this is where progress will be monitored     
      trace(e.bytesLoaded, e.bytesTotal); 
    }

    function onLoaderReady(e:Event) {     
          // the image is now loaded, so let's add it to the display tree!     
          Book.cover.addChild(myLoader);
          Book.play();
    }
}
```

I forgot where I found the code for this from  (I'm not all that familiar with AS, let alone AS3) but it worked in some earlier tests that I did.  From what I can tell it looks like `onLoaderReady` is never being called.  I have done some tests and `getCover` is indeed getting called from JavaScript, but it never gets to that final function call that it should get to once the image is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems to work fine for me when i add the http:// to the URL.

the only problem that i can see with this is that you don't have http:// in front of your url, which would throw an error otherwise

"Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found."

always put http:// in front of your URLs. thats really what makes it a url.